# Multiple reduceRegions for time series in GEE js

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to gather time series data (mean band values) from MODIS for multiple regions, but I want to filter the data so that I exclude images with low numbers of pixels in my regions.

Below is the code to use reduceRegions to get the pixel count and mean values, but how do I get exclude the images with low pixel counts?

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09GA")
  .randomColumn()
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.1))
  .limit(10)

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-142.36414308128087, 60.44668098352718],
              [-142.36414308128087, 60.171875701856855],
              [-141.62256593284337, 60.171875701856855],
              [-141.62256593284337, 60.44668098352718]]], null, false),
        {"site": "a"}),
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-150.47861099878585, 60.14760911377782],
              [-150.47861099878585, 59.90886167691271],
              [-149.84140396753585, 59.90886167691271],
              [-149.84140396753585, 60.14760911377782]]], null, false),
        {"site": "b"})
]);


// Mask some pixels
var maskModis = function(image){
  image = ee.Image(image)
  var ndsi = image
    .normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b06'])
  var ndsiMask = ndsi.gt(0.8)

  return image.updateMask(ndsiMask)
}

// Apply the mask
var modis = modis.map(maskModis)
// var testImg = ee.Image(modis.first())
// Map.addLayer(testImg)


// 1. Count number of pixels in each feature.
// Return FeatureCollection with date, site, and pixelCount.

var getPixelCount = function(image){
  image = ee.Image(image)
  var count = image
    .select(1)
    .reduceRegions({
      collection: fc,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      scale: 500
    })
  return count
}

var counts = modis
  .map(getPixelCount)
  .flatten()
print('counts', counts)

// 2. Get mean band values for each feature, each date
// Same appriach as (1), map reduceRegions

var getMeanVals = function(image){
  image = ee.Image(image)
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
  var mean = image
    .select('sur_refl_b01', 'sur_refl_b04')
    .reduceRegions({
      collection: fc,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 500 
    })
  return mean //returns featureCollection
    // add date to each elt in collection
    .map(function(f){
      return f.set({'date': date})
    })
}

var means = modis
  .map(getMeanVals)
  .flatten()
print('means', means)
```

This gives me two featureCollections, but I only care about the 'means' collection. How do I filter the 'means' collection by the 'counts' collection?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3AmultipleReduceRegions

Answer (score 1):

I filtered the 'counts' collection, then used an Inner Join to get the 'means' data. I could have used a Simple Join, but I figured I might want to keep the 'counts' data.

```
var countsFiltered = counts
  .filter(ee.Filter.gte('count', 1000))
print('filtered count size', countsFiltered.size()) // 7

// Criteria by which to join
var joinKey = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:index',
  rightField: 'system:index'
});

// Apply the join
var joined = ee.Join.inner()
  .apply(countsFiltered, means, joinKey)
  // tidy the output
  .map(function(f){
    var primary = ee.Feature(f.get('primary'))
    var secondary = ee.Feature(f.get('secondary'))
    var count = primary.get('count')
    return secondary
      .set('pixCount', count)
  })

print('filtered, joined collection', joined)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3AmultipleReduceRegions